# jqPlot highlighter change x value

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a jqPlot Line graph and I am trying to work out how to customise what the highlighter text is for the X value.

So. I have the following:

```
var line1=[100, 68, 63, 36, 28];
var line2=[100, 71, 68, 42, 32];
var line3=[100, 60, 45, 15, 5];
var line4=[100, 76, 58, 22, 8];
var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [line1,line2,line3,line4], {
axes:{
      xaxis: {
               ticks: [  [1, 'group1'], 
                         [2, 'group2'], 
                         [3, 'group3'], 
                         [4, 'group4'], 
                         [5, 'group5']
                      ],
               tickOptions:{
                      showGridline: false,
               },
            },
      yaxis:{
             label:'Percentage',
             labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
             min : 0,
             max : 100,
             pad : 0,
             numberTicks : 11,
            }
    },
```

Which displays the graph correctly, with the X-Axis reading group1 group2 etc...
however when I add the highlighter option and for example hover over line1 tick 2 the box displays "2.0, 68". What I would like it to do is display "group2, 68".

I have tried playing with the formatString parameter but cannot get it to work.

could someone point me in the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can come up with a solution, maybe not the best one, but the most appropriate one that I could quickly think of considering the code you showed. It involves the use of the below code. Basically on every mouse move, where the `neighbour` is not null (this is the condition used for showing of the highlighter tooltip) I am changing the tooltip to one I like.

```
$("#chart").bind('jqplotMouseMove', function(ev, gridpos, datapos, neighbor, plot) {
    if (neighbor) {
        $(".jqplot-highlighter-tooltip").html("" + plot.axes.xaxis.ticks[neighbor.pointIndex][1] + ", " + datapos.yaxis.toFixed(2) + " Oi");
    }
});
```

[For a working code sample please see.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/xJdkJ/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This solution was quick and easy to use. just copy/pasted, changed the "#chart" to match mine and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't try but this code seems to do what you are expecting https://gist.github.com/2422033

Here is the link on the JqPlot doc [highlighter plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html#%24.jqplot.Highlighter.tooltipAxes). Check the `tooltipAxes` property

And here there is a link on a solution to display the series name on tooltip which is not suported by default. Check comment #1
https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/109/enable-highlighter-tooltip-to-display-label-of-the-series-on#comment-65301

Comment: +1 for showing interesting links. Though I prefer to avoid changing the `jqPlot` script whenever I can avoid it, thus I provided a different answer.